# Post method of a form sends data to get method of a class based view

Tags: django

**Django 1.10.4**

There are two breakpoints.

Could you help me understand why the debugger stops at breakpoint 1?
The method is post. Why the flow is directed to get handler?

```
def form_view(request):
    html = """<form action='/testform' method="post">
                  <input name="q">
                  <input type=submit>
               </form>
               """
    return HttpResponse(html)

class TestHandler(View):
    def get(self, request):
        q = request.GET.get("q") # Breakpoint 1.
        return HttpResponse(q)

    def post(self, request):
        pass # Breakpoint 2.
        return HttpResponse(result)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/$', form_view, name='form'),
    url(r'^testform/$', TestHandler.as_view(), name='testform'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form action is "/testform" but your URL is "/testform/"; Django redirects from one to the other, but a redirect is always a GET.